# Finding no of non-negative integers satisfying the conditions

Tags: number-theory

The number of non-negative integers $n$ satisfying $n^2=p+q$ and $n^3=p^2+q^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers ?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: yes but i have no hint how to proceed in this ques

Comment: I think the answers are 0,1 and 2. Trying to prove it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You have that

$$n^4=(n^2)^2=(p+q)^2=p^2+q^2+2pq=n^3+2pq\le n^3+p^2+q^2=2n^3.$$ So, $n\le 2.$

Comment: May be a better way of saying that could be |n|<=2.

Comment: for someone who still has confusions: $p^{2}+q^{2}\ge2pq$